# Each function for input fields only uses value from the last element in class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a calculate that subtracts a user input from the quantity in a div. The issue I am having is that the first 2 items in my class update with the values inserted in the last class. I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly

```js
$('#go').on('click', function() {
  $('.second').each(function() {
    var first = $(this).parents().eq(1).find('.first').data('first');
    var second = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
    if ((second > 0) || (second = '')) {
      $(this).parents().eq(1).find('.first').text($(this).parents().eq(1).find('first').data('first'))
    }
    var newtotal = (first - second);
    if (newtotal >= 0) {
      $(this).parents().eq(1).find('.first').text(newtotal);
      $(this).parents().eq(1).find('.third').text(second);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class='first' data-first='50'>50</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='second' value='30'>
</div>
<div>
  <span class='third' data-third='0'>0</span>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <span class='first' data-first='50'>50</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='second' value='20'>
</div>
<div>
  <span class='third' data-third='0'>0</span>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <span class='first' data-first='50'>50</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='second' value='5'>
</div>
<div>
  <span class='third' data-third='0'>0</span>
</div>
<br/>

<br/><br/>
<button id='go'>Go!
```

Comment: Your input elements only have one parent element, the surrounding `<div>`. 
 `$(this).parents().get(1) === document.body`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/zwpcwxo1/

```js
$('#go').on('click', function() {
  $('.second').each(function() {
   $($(this).parent().prev().children()[0]).html(parseInt($($(this).parent().prev().children()[0]).attr('data-first')) - $(this).val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class='first' data-first='50'>50</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='second' value='30'>
</div>
<div>
  <span class='third' data-third='0'>0</span>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <span class='first' data-first='50'>50</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='second' value='20'>
</div>
<div>
  <span class='third' data-third='0'>0</span>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <span class='first' data-first='50'>50</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input class='second' value='5'>
</div>
<div>
  <span class='third' data-third='0'>0</span>
</div>
<br/>

<br/><br/>
<button id='go'>Go!
```

Code Change explanation

Instead of going through all the way I used **this** and then got the parent object i.e. **'div'**

Using **prev()** move one level up and grab the **'div'** which contains the span with value & got the **span data-first** using **children[0]** & then the calculation.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally not as helpful as those which explain the changes you've made to the OP's code.